# Как с помощью цикла for напечатать две последовательности

Tags: java

Как с помощью цикла for последовательно распечатать в консоли числа от 1 до 10 и от 15 до 25?

Comment: Создать цикл, напечатать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 26; i ++ )
        {
            if(i > 0 && i  < 11 || i >= 15 && i < 26)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Пока гуглил ответ на свой вопрос, написал данный код, все ли верно ?

Comment: *Пока гуглил ответ на свой вопрос* - это пять :)

Comment: Молодец. Но на больше 0 и меньше 26 можно не сравнивать, это уже задано в инициализации цикла.

Comment: `if (i <= 10 || i >= 15)`, начинать цикл с `int i = 1;`

Comment: а чем 2 цикла не подходят?